# How order by case and order too?

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-order-by

i have a query for my next table

```
|id |Name|type      |
---------------------
|1  |B   |Secondary |
|2  |A   |Scholar   |
|3  |C   |University|
```

This could be the sql query :

```
select * from invite order by  
        case "type" 
             when 'Scholar'   then 1 
             when 'Secondary' then 2
             when 'University' then 3
         end asc;
```

but now i need order by case:
example:  `when 'Scholar'   then 1  desc`

its possible do that?

my goal is order by **id**, and by case **type** example:

```
|id |Name|type      |
---------------------
|1  |B   |Secondary |
|2  |B   |Secondary |
|3  |B   |Secondary |
|4  |A   |Scholar   |
|5  |A   |Scholar   |
|6  |C   |University|
|7  |A   |Scholar.  |
```

the result will be:

```
|id |Name|type      |
---------------------
|7  |A   |Scholar.  |
|5  |A   |Scholar   |
|4  |A   |Scholar   |
|3  |B   |Secondary |
|2  |B   |Secondary |
|1  |B   |Secondary |
|6  |C   |University|
```

Comment: Please provide an example of what you mean by showing the results you want.  "1" is a constant.  It doesn't make a difference if it is ascending or descending.

Comment: . . I don't see that "scholar" is any different from the other groups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question suggests that want a new direction within each group:

```
order by (case "type" 
             when 'Scholar'   then 1 
             when 'Secondary' then 2
             when 'University' then 3
          end) asc;
         (case when "type" = Scholar then id end) desc,
         id asc;
```

However, your example suggests that you just want a second `order by` key, `id desc`.

Comment: this should be to all the cases : (case when status = SENT then id end) desc,

Comment: @jdode . . . Then you just want `id desc` as the second `order by` key.

Comment: how can i order by other parameter over? by id and name

Comment: @jdode . . . You can add additional keys.  I'm not sure where you want that particular ordering.

Comment: in this part in this part 
             when 'University' then 3
          end) asc and name;

Comment: can you help me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63021988/how-can-i-order-by-many-case

Answer (score 1):

I think you want:

```
order by  
    case "type" 
         when 'Scholar'    then 1 
         when 'Secondary'  then 2
         when 'University' then 3
    end,
    id desc
```

You can also use arrays instead of conditional logic:

```
order by
    array_position(array['Scholar', 'Secondary', 'University'], "type"),
    id desc
```